# Spring boot dashboard isn't active

Tags: spring

Spring boot dashboard do not active in my VSCode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdQBE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC5rL.png)

```
Cannot activate the 'Spring Boot Dashboard' extension because it depends on an unknown 'Pivotal.vscode-spring-boot' extension.
```

I tried to reinstalled VSCode remove folders with prefix like "redhat.java", "vscjava.vscode-spring-boot-dashboard", "vscjava.vscode-java-debug", "pivotal.vscode-spring-boot".

Comment: Having the same issue here. Reinstall + deleting all vscode related folders doesn't seem to fix anything at all.

Comment: Yep, I'm having the same issue too.

Comment: I think it's fixed. Updated to the latest version just now(2023/02/01 08:55 AM GMT+8), and the dashboard is being launched properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
install other version
Spring Boot Tools: 1.43.0
Spring Boot Dashboard: 0.9.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).